# PySide6 hidePopup function explanation please

Tags: python, inheritance, combobox, pyside6

I'm currently building a desktop application using some checkable comboboxes.
I've used the code snippet we can find easily on the web about how customizing comboboxes to make the items checkable.
It 's been working fine but I wanted each combobox list not to collapse once any item was selected.
That's where the virtual function hidePopup(self) comes in: I only had to define it within the checkable combobox class, without any code!!,  to prevent the popup list from hiding... I don't understand why since there is absolutely no code but "pass" in my functions!
You'll find below the script from the checkable combobox class.

```py
class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.liste_artisans = []
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handle_item_pressed)
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handle_item_pressed(self, index):
        # getting which item is pressed
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        # make it check if unchecked and vice-versa
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
       
        self.checked_items_list()

    def checked_items_list(self):
        for i in range(self.count()):  
            text_label = self.model().item(i, 0).text()
            
            if self.item_check_status(i) and text_label not in self.liste_artisans:
                self.liste_artisans.append(text_label)
            
            elif not self.item_check_status(i) and text_label in self.liste_artisans:
                self.liste_artisans.remove(text_label)
  
    def hidePopup(self):
        pass

    # method called by checked_items_list
    def item_check_status(self, index):

        # getting item at index
        item = self.model().item(index, 0)

        # return true if checked else false
        return item.checkState() == Qt.Checked
```

Comment: "I don't understand why since there is absolutely no code but "pass" in my functions!" -> that's the whole point: `hidePopup()` *hides* the popup, if you don't implement it, the instance will use the default behavior, which *actually* hides the popup. If you override it and do nothing in that override, then the popup will not close, because you're not telling it to close.

Comment: Thank you very much Musicamente, that's pretty easy to understand, even if overriding it by merely implementing hidePopup() with "pass" is not intuitive ;-)